# Want to grep a date in a file and its next 5 lines

Tags: grep, aix

I want to grep the current date in a file, but also output the next 5 lines. How do i do that with the grep or anything else. `grep -A 5 file.txt` does not work and the output is shown below. Please help !

`$grep $(date +"%m/%d") file.txt` - this works only for the first line. But i want the next 5 lines displayed as well.

```
$ grep -A 5 '$(date +"%m/%d")' file.txt
grep: Not a recognized flag: A
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]
```

Comment: I can't see an error with your command. Try, `cat file.txt | grep -A 5 '$(date +"%m/%d")'

Comment: Please run `grep -V` for us. Are you on SunOS/Solaris with its notoriously frugal tools?

Comment: I just verified `grep -A 5 "$(date +"%b %d")" /var/log/syslog` works for me just fine. But as Ulrich suggests it could be a picky version of grep.

Comment: I am using AIX. grep -V does not work either. displays $ grep -V
grep: Not a recognized flag: V
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your grep doesn't support the `-A` flag, so you can't use that. But you should be able to get the same result with `awk`.

```
awk -v dt=$(date +%m/%d) '$0~dt{counter=5}counter>=0{print;counter--}' file.txt
```

This sets a counter to 5 when a match is found, and prints and decrements the counter while it's not negative.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Works like a charm. :)

Comment: I believe that this prints only the matching line and the next *four*.  The matching line + the next five = six lines, so you need to set `counter=6`.

Comment: @G-Man: you're right, fixed.

Comment: correct i changed it to 6 and then works like a charm :)